# What are people doing about browser degradation and HTML5

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, browser-detection

I am in the process of updating my business website and I've decided to use HTML5/CSS3 (with some PHP) for the whole thing and it works fantastic in every new browser (IE9, FF6, O11, S5, C13) with or without JS.

Now I am not sure what I should do about every other browser version. I imagine I have a small amount of leeway with most of the browsers (atleast the previous version) except IE8 (I have the IE shiv, but it doesn't cover non-js browsers.). Most of the features degrade nicely, but there will always be issues with older browsers.

- *I know nonJS browsers are probably a minority, but it would be  nice
  to cover them as well*
- *This list is ordered in the order of current preference to cover the
  largest number of browsers(nonJS/JS) but time to implement hasn't been
  considered.*
- *Only considering web-browsers, plan is for a mobile site for mobile browsers*

  Here is the list:

  1. Build a really dodge version of the site using tables^, etc. and redirect the users there if they have an old version of the browser (server-side) and have a warning on there about upgrading.
  2. Use Javascript to fix up the bits they don't work (like the shiv). This doesn't really cover the nonJS browsers which as stated are probably a minority.
  3. Build a static old browser page to redirect the old browser users to a page with links to upgrade download links. This is a real copout solutions, but is quick to implement
  4. Assume the only users that have old browsers are IE users, and use conditional comments to implement one of the previous options. **Assumptions are always bad**
  5. Pretend users have the most upto date browsers and make no attempt to fix the site at all. **Not really a practical option**
  6. Rebuild the website for HTML4 and use it accross the site. **Bit of a waste of current work. As well as it looks a bit dissappointing if a webdeveloper has a site using old technologies, which was the driving force for the upgrade**

What are your thoughts/solutions to the HTML4/5 limbo? Is there anything you've done in current projects to combat this?

Cheers,

Steve.

P.S. Being a member of the 'I hate IE6 and don't care for it's existance' club, I'm pretending that IE6 (or less) never existed.

**Update (to clarify)**

^ - by tables, I mean are really slapped together version of the current website, using either a table/non-table based layout. But something that may not look pretty when the source is viewed, it's really just there to fill the compatibility void.

Comment: Check the visitor stats for your business web-site? What's the cumulative share of the "problematical" browsers?

Comment: Why would using tables make it work in older browsers? Older browsers too understand table-less layouts...

Comment: Could you give some examples for the HTML/CSS features that you want to use and that don't work in older browsers?

Comment: @Šime Vidas. It's nothing it particular, I am really just using my website as a context to the question because it is my most current project. The comment about table based layout was mainly because if I was going to go that route, I would probably just slap something together (table based or not) to fill the gap (have altered question to reflect this). As for the HTML/CSS tags, for the sake of question it's nothing in particular, I am mainly concerned with site wide solutions that people have adopted.

Comment: @Cubed Check out [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly acceptable to have features in some browsers and no features for an older browser. See [Here](http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com).

However, it should be noted that whenever a fix is doable, you should have it. Unless a website is a JavaScript based app, it should be **working** without JavaScript, note that **working != working perfectly**.

if you have a hover state with a cool transition, which Chrome 23423 will support, but IE7 won't, then you can either emulate it using **[Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)** and jQuery, or leave it as is, and IE7 won't enjoy the goodness. BooHoo.

You must however, give older browser users a message to encourage them to upgrade to a better ones, especially talking about IE<=7.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I've avoided js where possible, and that part works fine. I will definitely have a look at Modernizr.

Answer (score 1):

You built the website in the wrong direction.

If you want to support older versions, instead of building a cutting edge website and then trying to get it to work in older browsers, you need to build a basic site that works everywhere, then use advanced CSS and Javascript feature detection to add features for the newest browsers.